# Is there a package in Django with article editor

Tags: python, django, wysiwyg

I'm looking for a package with Django that could help to write article.
Something in Django admin that could be the same editor as wikipedia when someone write an article : ad texte, ad title, ad image, ad link...., AD hyperlink...

Thanks a lot if you have any idea.

For the moment my dirty solution is to write HTML directly in the database.

Gonzague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [django richtextfield](https://pypi.org/project/django-richtextfield/) or more comprehensive [django-wiki](https://github.com/django-wiki/django-wiki)